# how to implement angular2 material in sail.js?

Tags: angular, sails.js, angular-material2

What is the `layout.js` file in `sails.js`, to implement angular 2 material in `sails.js`?

What are the changes we have to make in `layout.js` which is the `system.config.js` file in angular2?

Can anyone explain clearly about this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to make sails/angular application is to to do it by REST API based architecture. You remove views from sails and create REST APIs for standalone Angular2 application. Then you use angular 2 material in Angular2. This way you will have least of problems.

Comment: can you give me the explanation about how to integrate frontend and backend in this application?

Comment: As I figured out, you want to use Angular in sails because you don't like sails default templating engine EJS. But you want to figure out how do that MVC way (Model View Controller) like EJS is now. However, angular is not made for this kind of use case, It is made mostly for REST API architecture. What this means in terms of your question is that if you want to use Angular with Sails, you need to do this as Sails in backend and Angular as frontend application.

Comment: Those are two different applications, you would delete Sails view part totally and make controllers return JSON responses (res.json()). And then, you would retrieve JSON response from Sails backend using Angular 2 service and http module. 
You can try and integrate angular in sails too, this way imagined, but I am not sure what is waiting for you down to that path. It is not recommended way to use angular with sails. If you want to try, you have tutorial here: 
http://sharpten.com/blog/2016/02/02/integrating-angular-2-with-sails-js.html

Comment: yes, your recommended way is the good approach in this application but I got confused coming to DB connection.

Comment: Ok, I just assumed some things, sorry. Your backend part (sails with only models and controllers) will be connected to Database, and you will build REST APIs in sails controllers, which you can use in Angular through Angular 2 services (http module Angular 2). So sails would be serving data from database to your Angular 2 client application.

Comment: Yes, you got me now exactly.